# Error loading Info.plist template file

Tags: xamarin-studio, monomac, info.plist

Using Xamarin Studio with MonoMac (latest version: 5.4), I tried building [a C# solution](https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync).

I receive this error:

```
Error loading Info.plist template file
'[ProjectFile: FileName=/Users/nico/src/CmisSync/CmisSync/Mac/Info.plist]'.
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It just means that the file `Info.plist` is missing.

In this case, `Info.plist` must first [be generated](https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync/blob/master/CmisSync/Mac/README.md).